# how to display ? marquee in php mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, marquee

I am trying to make marquee text in php using mysql data but this is script showing only simple mysql data. How can i showing marquee on my php page? Please help me to fix this issue.
Thanks

```
   <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("something.com","someusername","somepassword.","somedatabase");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM itomi");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
    echo "{$row['ntitle']}: {$row['ndetails']} ";
       echo "</font></marquee>";
      }

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: where `</font></marquee>` start tags

Comment: might he didnt gave password @ asprin. but i flagged your comment as important

Comment: db username password are just for only example its not correct dear

Comment: Your code is quite crappy - you check if connection was successful, if not, you show the error message... and continue like nothing has happened?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope u want to print list in a marquee

```
echo "<font><marquee>";

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
    echo "{$row['ntitle']}: {$row['ndetails']} <br>";

      }

echo "</font></marquee>";
```

Comment: can u tell me how can i give a link in ndetail row

Comment: A tip is to use http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/ for smoother... marquees.

Comment: echo "{$row['ntitle']}: <a href='newpage.php'>{$row['ndetails']}</a> <br>";